# How to unhide a hidden html <p> tag element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, hide, show-hide

I have the following hidden `<p>` element in the body tag of my HTML file (for my chrome extension).

```
<p hidden id="button">
    <a id="dashboard-btn" href="www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      www.google.com
    </a>
</p>
```

I want to unhide this using **JavaScript**. My random try that failed to unhide it:

```
document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

**[SOLVED]** This (also) worked:

```
document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: why dont you hide with `display: none` and unhide it with `display: block`? or use `element.removeAttribute(attrName)`?

Comment: @tacoshy Why remove attribute instead of use the property of hidden attribute?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, if we replace display none with visibility hidden, then we can make a beautiful transition. And changing attribute directly or through the setter is not a big difference. But I think directly, like you mention is a more clean way

Comment: In 20+ years of using html I have never seen the `hidden` html attribute used in the wild. And I did not know it existed. Reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) makes me consider using it as opposed to my current method of creating a class named "hidden" with `display: none` and adding or removing that class as needed. Any advice regarding that?

Comment: @RobMoll, I think it is more about semantics and whether you want to animate the element from hidden state to visible, or no.

Comment: @RobMoll, I have also never seen it until now. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute('hidden')
```

```html
<p hidden id="button">
  <a id="dashboard-btn" 
     href="www.google.com" 
     target="_blank" 
     rel="noopener noreferrer">
      www.google.com
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Furthermore, this also worked: `document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 3):

You hide your element with attribute `hidden` so you need to control that attribute instead of style like:

```js
document.getElementById("button").hidden = false;
```

```html
<p hidden id="button">
    <a id="dashboard-btn" href="www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      www.google.com
    </a>
</p>
```

Reference:

- [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute("hidden")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the attribute "hidden".

`document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute("hidden")`

Answer (score 0):

I have several solutions:

### A

```
document.getElementById("button").hidden = "false";
```

---

As hidden is not a css **visibility : hidden;** property.

*It is an attribute.*

### B

**As @tacoshi mentioned,**

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opaicty 1s ease;
  /* use opacity in case you want to have a beautiful transition */
}
```

And just use

```
document.getElementById("button").classList.toggle("hidden")
```